# Connecting Oracle XE DB / Oracle Database 10g Express

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, connection, oracle10g

I started with Oracle DB. On Windows Server 2003 I installed Oracle Database 10g Express Edition and then I also installed PL SQL Developer.

I tried log on via PL SQL Developer to XE database.

I use this credentials:

- Username: system
- Password: password is correct :)
- Database: XE

I got this error: **ORA-12528**.  So I google it and tried this solution:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_12528_tns_listener_all_appropriate_instances_are_blocking_new_connection_tips_bc1.htm:

```
SQL> conn system as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.

SQL> $ lsnrctl


LSNRCTL> stop
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
The command completed successfully
```

and again start listener

```
LSNRCTL> start
Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\ad
min\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\log
\listener.log
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC_FOR
_XEipc)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=jan)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                24-J┌N-2011 19:14:14
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 1 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\l
og\listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC_FOR_XEipc)))
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=jan)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

---

Then I tried again connect to XE database via PL SQL Developer but I got error  **ORA 12514**.

I **checked** the listener log file (**listener.log**), here is it output:

```
System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\log\listener.log
Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\trace\listener.trc
Trace level is currently 0

Started with pid=2964
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC_FOR_XEipc)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=jan)(PORT=1521)))
Listener completed notification to CRS on start

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
24-JÚN-2011 19:17:52 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=Administrator))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
24-JÚN-2011 19:18:19 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\Program Files\PLSQL Developer\plsqldev.exe)(HOST=JAN)(USER=Administrator))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.5.100)(PORT=2907)) * establish * XE * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
24-JÚN-2011 19:18:48 * service_register * xe * 0
```

---

Here I put configs.

**tnsname.ora**

```
XE =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = jan)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
   )
 )
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SID = PLSExtProc)
     (PRESENTATION = RO)
   )
 )
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SID = CLRExtProc)
     (PRESENTATION = RO)
   )
 )
```

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC =
     (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
     (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
     (PROGRAM = extproc)
   )
   (SID_DESC =
     (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
     (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
     (PROGRAM = extproc)
   )
 )

LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = jan)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

---

I tried made a change in tsname.ora and change SERVICE_NAME to SID

```
XE =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = jan)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SID = XE)
   )
 )
```

But I got error:

```
**ORA-12505** TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

---

I remove change (SID = XE => SERVICE_NAME=XE) in tsname.ora and finaly I checked status of listener with command.

```
LSNRCTL> stat
```

Result is here:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                24-J┌N-2011 19:30:31
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 5 min. 57 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\l
og\listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC_FOR_XEipc)))
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=jan)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE_XPT" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "xe", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "xe", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

---

I tried **restarted OracleServiceXE** (Control panel > Adminstrative Toolls > Services>)

---

Last attempt to solve this problem was to connect to XE via cmd.

```
SQL> conn system/jano@XE
ERROR:
ORA-12528: TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections
```

Nothing works. I can not connect to XE.

This is my first time when I deal with Oracle DB. What is root of problem and how can solve this issue.

Thank you for cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

once disable your all network connections then restart your PC/Server and then try to log in. if it is successful enable your all network connections.